# Rails simple_form inputs not clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, simple-form-for

I am using simple_form with rails 4.  The form seems to work properly, except i cannot click on any of the input fields.  When i try to click on them, nothing happens, and I can't enter text.  Here is the code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @mimic, url: create_employer_account_path, html: {id: 'braintree-payment-form'}, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="forms clearfix" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 35%;">
            <h1>Personal / Business Information</h1>
            <p style="margin-top: 15px;" class="clearfix">
                <%= f.input :first_name, input_html: {class: 'field', style: 'width: 300px;', id: 'first_name'}, required: true %>
            </p>
            <p style="margin-top: 15px;" class="clearfix">
                <%= f.input :last_name, input_html: {class: 'field', style: 'width: 300px;', id: 'last_name'}, required: true %>
            </p>
            <p style="margin-top: 15px;" class="clearfix">
                <%= f.input :company, input_html: {class: 'field', style: 'width: 300px;', id: 'company'} %>
            </p>
            <p style="margin-top: 15px;" class="clearfix">
                <%= f.input :email, input_html: {class: 'field', style: 'width: 300px;', id: 'email'}, required: true %>
            </p>
            <p style="margin-top: 15px;" class="clearfix">
                <%= f.input :phone, input_html: {class: 'field', style: 'width: 300px;', id: 'phone'} %>
            </p>
            <p style="margin-top: 15px;" class="clearfix">
                <%= f.input :fax, input_html: {class: 'field', style: 'width: 300px;', id: 'fax'} %>
            </p>
            <p style="margin-top: 15px;" class="clearfix">
                <%= f.input :website, input_html: {class: 'field', style: 'width: 300px;', id: 'website'} %>
            </p>
    </div>
        <p class="buttons action-buttons text-center">
            <%= f.submit "SUBMIT", class: 'submit-button button button-save button-submit'%>
        </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you share the css which your are using in this form.

Comment: remove all css and javascript on that page and try again